# AppSheet Guidance Needed

Tags: google-sheets

I know this is a basic question, but I've been hitting my head against the wall for a few days. I have used Appscript quite a lot, but know my employer wants a project done in appsheet. I have studied a lot of the sample apples to reproduce the functionality, but I am simply not getting the same behavior in my app.

I'm willing to put in the time but all the learning material I've come across is not much better that hello world type of stuff. I've checked; udemy, coursera, linkedin learning, linux academy, google documentation, youtube,etc.

All I'm try to do is make a flow chart. ex.

```
1. Are the hallways clear 
    if yes -> go to next page --> end
    if no -> go to question 2 on the next page
2. Is the hallway clear enough to roll larger equipment through
    if yes --> go to next page 3a.
    if no --> go to page 3b.
3a. Did you clear the hallway yourself
     if yes --> go to 4a
     if no --> go to 3b.
3b. Do you want to send a departmental email
```

As I said, I am willing to learn but can't find suitable material. Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone having the same problem, I figured out (in general) how to do this. It requires the use of pages. I am using google sheets as my "database". So when you are building the schema, you would make columns for the options above. For each of the numbers above you would create columns (i.e. Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, etc) for each section. In the data section of your app (using the column view) you would set the type of each page cloumn to "show".

Then, you would add conditional show logic to each question. So it might be something like the following:

For the filtered show option for #1 No, you would have

[Are the hallways clear]="Yes"

What you're telling appsheet is to only show the second part of #1 if the answer to the first part of #1 above is "yes". You would do the same thing going down the line.

If anyone else has problems, please leave a comment and I will follow up.